# derive schema in pyspark giving Value Error

Tags: rest, pyspark, schema

I have a JSON response from a rest API call :

```json
{
    "metadata": {
        "count": 2
    },
    "payload": [
                {
            "id": "12",
            "id1": "90",
            "id2": "2",
            "year": " 2025"
        },
        {
            "id": "13",
            "id1": "100",
            "id2": "3",
            "year": " 2023"
        }
    ]
}
```

Wanted to write a schema for this to pass to a udf.

This is how it looks like:

```py
schema = StructType([
    StructField("metadata", StringType(), True),
    StructField("payload", ArrayType(
    StructType([
        StructField("id", IntegerType()),
        StructField("id1", IntegerType())
    ])
    ))
])
```

While passing this schema to the udf and calling it, it is giving following error:

```
'ValueError: Unexpected tuple with StructType
```

I was trying to generate schema from a Rest API response and I was expecting it would return me a JSON type.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the nested struct type "count" and also have type mismtatch for "id", "id1" etc.

Also, while passing data to `createDateframe()`, the type has to be an iterable like array, list etc. It won't accept dictionary or JSON object.

The correct schema looks like following:

```py
data = {"metadata":{"count":2},"payload":[{"id":"12","id1":"90","id2":"2","year":"2025"},{"id":"13","id1":"100","id2":"3","year":"2023"}]}

schema = StructType([
    StructField(
        "metadata", 
        StructType([
            StructField("count", IntegerType())
        ])
    ),
    StructField(
        "payload",
        ArrayType(
            StructType([
                StructField("id", StringType()),
                StructField("id1", StringType()),
                StructField("id2", StringType()),
                StructField("year", StringType()),
            ])
        )
    )
])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[data], schema=schema)

df.show(truncate=False)

+--------+---------------------------------------+
|metadata|payload                                |
+--------+---------------------------------------+
|{2}     |[{12, 90, 2, 2025}, {13, 100, 3, 2023}]|
+--------+---------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Does this solve your problem?